# Axios Error: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, post, axios, postman

I used Springboot to create the API for a coach booking app. In postman, When I make a POST on http://localhost:8081/customers or http://localhost:8081/employees it gets posted to MySQL database with 200 ok response. I tried to connect the API to the frontend using AXIOS. been receiving this error always in the console and can't find a way to fix it:

> M {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'.

I don't use any frontend frameworks; just HTML, CSS, JS only.

My register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Europe Bus | Register</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Europe Bus</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html#top">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#features">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="auth">
      <div class="container">
        <form id="register-form" class="register-form">
          <h2>Register</h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required value="Brian" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required value="Minke" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address (Username)</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required value="bmdtrinke@yahoo.com" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required value="123124sda" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select id="gender" name="gender">
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" required value="1995-01-10" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required value="0779261840" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <textarea id="address" name="address" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-type">User Type</label>
            <select id="user-type" name="user-type">
              <option value="customer">Customer</option>
              <option value="employee">Employee</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="login-link">
          <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Click here to login</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <p>&copy; 2023 Europe Bus. All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <script src="register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my register.js file

```
// Set the base URL for API requests
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8081";

// Get the form element
const registerForm = document.querySelector(".register-form");

// Add event listener for form submission
registerForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

  // Get form data
  const firstName = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
  const surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  const gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  const dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  const phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  const userType = document.getElementById("user-type").value;
  const address = document.getElementById("address").value;

  // Create user object
  const user = {
    firstName,
    surname,
    email,
    password,
    gender,
    dob,
    phone,
    address,
  };

  // Make API request to save user based on user type
  if (userType === "customer") {
    axios
      .post("/customers", user)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Customer registered successfully");
        alert("Customer registration successful!");
        // Redirect to login page or perform any other action
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error registering customer:", error);
        alert("Customer registration failed. Please try again.");
        // Handle the error or display a specific error message
      });
  } else if (userType === "employee") {
    axios
      .post("/employees", user)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Employee registered successfully");
        alert("Employee registration successful!");
        // Redirect to login page or perform any other action
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error registering employee:", error);
        alert("Employee registration failed. Please try again.");
        // Handle the error or display a specific error message
      });
  } else {
    // Handle unsupported user types or display an error message
    console.error("Unsupported user type:", userType);
    alert("Invalid user type. Please try again.");
  }
});
```

I believe the error should be either on the register.html or the register.js in which I used AXIOS since its working fine on Postman. I'm a bit new to coding and would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Compare your request data and headers from the frontend vs. Postman and take note of any differences that might be causing the issue

Comment: It was an issue with wrong ids. I was passing an incorrect JSON data using AXIOS to API. Wherea I was using the correct format on postman. Used the same format it was in there and issue was fixed. Thanks for the tip too.